# javascript parse all within certain characters from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am wondering if it is possible to parse out the contents from this string eliminating the `` piece. My goal is to have the the below string return an array of the 3 http requests without the ```. Thanks!

something like:

````
 string.match(/```(.*?)```/)


"HTTP Request 1:↵```↵GET /url; HTTP/1.1↵Host: {{ip_address}}:{{port}}↵Connection: keep-alive↵Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate↵Accept: */*↵```↵↵HTTP Request 2:↵```↵GET /url; HTTP 1/1↵Host: {{ip_address}}:{{port}}↵Connection: keep-alive↵Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate↵Accept: */*↵```↵↵HTTP Request 3:↵```↵GET /url; HTTP/1.1↵Host: {{ip_address}}:{{port}}↵Connection: keep-alive↵Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate↵Accept: */*↵```↵"
````

Answer (score 1):

You can use String.split()

````js
let str = "HTTP Request 1:↵```↵GET /url; HTTP/1.1↵Host: {{ip_address}}:{{port}}↵Connection: keep-alive↵Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate↵Accept: */*↵```↵↵HTTP Request 2:↵```↵GET /url; HTTP 1/1↵Host: {{ip_address}}:{{port}}↵Connection: keep-alive↵Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate↵Accept: */*↵```↵↵HTTP Request 3:↵```↵GET /url; HTTP/1.1↵Host: {{ip_address}}:{{port}}↵Connection: keep-alive↵Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate↵Accept: */*↵```↵"


console.log(str.split('```'));
````